# Retrieve an array whose elements are linked with other arrays in C#

Tags: c#, arrays

I must populate an array with uint variable like this:

```
uint[] idsArray = { 107, 22, 51 };
```

I do not know the size of this array!

The elements of this array must be linked with other uint arrays like:

```
A1 - `{80,61,47,2,1}` , A2 - `{6,207}`, A3 - `{14,36,88,37,45}`.
```

I do not know also the size of these arrays! All the time the number of these arrays correspond with the size of idsArray!

For 107 element value of the idsArray it must be linked with A1, for 22 with A2 , for 51 with A3.

For example when I put the idsArray elements in a column box, when I click on the first element - 107 - for example it must display in another list the elements of A1. If I click on the second element - 22 it must display the elements of A2 array and so on. What is the best way to accomplish this scenario in C#? I have tried with arrays but it not works because I do not know anything about the size and the initialization values for any arrays above!

Comment: What is your doubt specifically? What you tried already and which part are you blocked? To get the size of the array, just do ```idsArray.Length```

Comment: How exactly the elements in the arrays are linked?

Comment: I'm new to C#. I do not know which is the best approach. I try using jagged array but it doesn't help me because I do not know the size of the idsArray. As I said it must be a logical link between idsArray elements and the others array and I must retain this links in some way to be used in a form view list boxes but  also wneh i return the data back to the main program . this is part of an Add-in dll

Comment: Important: I do not know anything about idsArray, or A1, A2, A3, etc in the moment I declare them in the code. All of the the values indicated above are just as an example,They must be retrieved into this form as arrays !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a job for `Dictionary`:

```
var dict =  new Dictionary<int, int[]>() 
{
  { 107, new int[] {80,61,47,2,1} },
  { 22, new int[] {6,207} },
  { 51, new int[] {14,36,88,37,45} },
};
```

And then, in order to access particular array, just use:

```
var array = dict[107];
```

Comment: Interesting! Can I declare a dictionary like you do but with empty parameters (because i do not know them at declaration moment) and after that fill it using for cycle?

Comment: You can initialize a drictionary without content: `var dict =  new Dictionary<int, int[]>() ;` and add entries later on: `dict.Add(108, new int[] { 1, 2 })`. If you modify your arrays you should think about using `List<int>()` wihtin your dictionary.